# Determining page numbers and offsets for given addresses

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, offset, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

Consider a computer system with a 32-bit logical address and 4KB page size. The system supports up to 512MB of physical memory.

> How many entries are there in a conventional single-level page table?
>
> ```
> Conventional single-level page table: 2^32 / 2^12 (4000)  = 2^20 = 1,048,576
> ```

Why did I have to `divide 2^32 / 2^12` to get the answer?

> How many entries are there in an inverted page table?
>
> An inverted page table needs as many entries as there are page frames
>   in memory.
>
> ```
> Inverted page table: 2^29 (512mb)/ 2^12 (4000) = 2^17 = 131,072
> ```

Why did I have to `divide 512mb / page size` to get the inverted page table entries?

> What are the page numbers and offsets for the following address
>   references: a) 30000, b) 256, c) 0xbcf034
>
> a) 30000 in hex: x7530  Page #: x7 = 7 offset: x530 = 1328
>
> b) 256 in hex x100  Page #: x0 = 0 offset: x100 = 256
>
> c) 0xbcf034 Page #: xbcf = 3023 offset: x034 = 22

How do I figure out these page numbers and offsets based on the hex addresses?

I know the answers and but I want to understand WHY and HOW. Can someone please explain in detail :)

Comment: In inverted page table,all the frames are mapped not the pages.therefore,the entries in the inverted page table consist of total number of FRAMES,thats what you are calculating.

Comment: PS: 4K is not 4000 :-)

Answer (score 14):

***Why did I have to divide 2^32 / 2^12 to get the answer?***

2^32 ==> Total virtual memory size

4KB=2^12 ==> Size of a single page

2^32 / 2^12 =2^20 ==> Total number of pages of virtual memory

So page table will be having 2^20 = 1M entries

***How many entries are there in an inverted page table?***

2^29=512MB ==> Total physical memory

2^12 = page size = frame size

2^29 / 2^12 =2^17 ==> Total number of frames in physical memory

So inverted page table will be having 2^17 = 128K entries

***This fig. may clear your remaining doubts:***

[image]

Comment: What about: how many entries are there in a two-level hierarchical page table ?

Answer (score 5):

Given page size and address references : 

 best way to Calculate page number and offset, 

Suppose, page size of is 1KB and address reference is 256.

---

```
Page number = (address reference / page size) = 256/1024 = 0
```

---

```
Offset = (address reference % page size) = (256 % 2014) = 256
```

---

Apply the same procedure for the rest of the address references.

Answer (score 0):

2^12 => 4096
2^32/2^12 => 2^32/4096 => how many 4K pages are there => how many page table entries we need.

Similar calculation for the physical page table i.e. how many page table entries do we need for the inverted page table.

With the above hint, give the question a shot and let us know what you come up with. Once you learn a bit more in your OS course, you will find out that there are pros and cons in each page table design.

Comment: Why do you need to know the physical page table entries for the inverted page table? PS - thx

Comment: For this you need to study some theory on inverted page tables....a quick answer is that inverted page tables are sized proportional to the number of physical pages in the system. The normal (or logical) page table is sized for the entire virtual address space of the process i.e the sized on the number of virtual pages in a process. i.e. Inverted page table: one entry for one physical page; Logical or Virtual page table: one entry for one virtual page. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

because page size = frame size = 2^12
number of entries in inverted page table  = no of frames 
so we are calculating no of frames